# DeviceIoControl giving ERROR_BAD_LENGTH error when called in DLL

Tags: c++, winapi

I am want to find the type of drive for that i used DeviceIoControl function which is working. However when I use the same function in DLL it returns with ERROR_BAD_LENGTH error. Following is my code.

```
BOOL Globals::IsUsbDevice ( wchar_t letter)
{
    wchar_t volumeAccessPath[] = L"\\\\.\\X:";
    volumeAccessPath [4] = letter;

    HANDLE deviceHandle= CreateFileW(
    volumeAccessPath,
    0,               // no access to the Drive
    FILE_SHARE_READ | // Share mode
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,             // Default Security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING,    // Disposition
    0,                // file attributes
    NULL);            //  do not Copy file attributes

    if (deviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)    // cannot open the drive
    {
        CloseHandle (deviceHandle);
        return (FALSE);
    }

  // Setup query
    STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY Query;
    memset (&Query, 0, sizeof (Query));
    Query.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
    Query.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;

  // Issue query
  DWORD bytes;
  //STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR Devd;
  STORAGE_BUS_TYPE busType = BusTypeUnknown;

  char OutBuf[1024] = {0};  // good enough, usually about 100 bytes
  PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR pDevDesc = (PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR)OutBuf;
  pDevDesc->Size = sizeof(OutBuf);

    if (DeviceIoControl (deviceHandle,
   IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
   &Query, sizeof(STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY),
   pDevDesc, pDevDesc->Size,
   &bytes,NULL))
  {
   busType = pDevDesc->BusType;
  }
  else
  {
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code    
    ..........
  }

  CloseHandle (deviceHandle);

  return BusTypeUsb == busType;
}
```

I am executing my program as Administrator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code works fine for me... have you seen this code? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6559/How-To-get-the-usbdisk-s-drive-letter-properly

Comment: @JochenKalmbach Ya the code is working fine but gives error in DLL. I already checked your provided link. Also my code is almost the same. Did you checked in DLL ?

Comment: What do you mean "in DLL". It should not matter where the code is executed, because there is no relationship to the EXE/DLL...

Comment: When the IsUsbDevice function is called within the program it works fine but when it is included as Class function in DLL it starts to give ERROR_BAD_LENGTH at DeviceIoControl function.

Comment: Double check the differences in build options (EXE vs DLL). Double check (trace or debugger) that the `letter` argument has the expected input value.

Comment: @manuell I created the MFC DLL using visual studio wizard and DLL project configuration type is Dynamic Library but what do u mean by "differences in build options". 
I checked the "letter" argument and its fine and the device handle is also valid. By the way my Globals class is static and this class has many other static functions which are working OK, also DLL has many other Dialog classes and they are also working properly. I am calling Globals::IsUsbDevice from a DLL Dialog class.

Comment: By "build options", I mean anything which may be different in the two test cases (EXE vs DLL). Does the Release/Debug builds behave the same?